# jQuery slider throwing error: ...Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLAnchorElement.appendChild]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Our dev site has the slider working perfectly here:

http://allblacks.01dev.co.nz/index.cfm?layout=dnaHome

However, we've just put the site live and it's not working here:

http://www.allblacks.com/index.cfm?layout=dnaHome

There is a js error viewable in firebug, which I have little hope of understanding without some help...

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLAnchorElement.appendChild]
```

though that seems to be related to a facebook script

I'm happy to provide additional information if required.
Any pointers greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** There is now a new question concerning this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289399/slider-not-running-with-window-load), which better explains the problem after more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined the problem was related to thickbox javascript not being called properly or some type of conflict. We moved the thickbox js call to the top of the list of js calls (ahead of the jQuery.js call) and this seemed to solve the problem.